# Flutter Tabbar NoSuchMethodError: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: dart, flutter, tabbar

I am building an app using flutter that has a TabBar that is used to filter a listview by categories. However, when the TabBar is initiated it throws the following error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building _TabStyle(animation: kAlwaysDismissedAnimation,
flutter: dirty, state: _AnimatedState#71498):
flutter: The method 'withAlpha' was called on null.
flutter: Receiver: null
flutter: Tried calling: withAlpha(178).....
```

Code was working fine initially. But the simulator now no longer renders the tapBar at all. Instead the simulator has a error stating that the bottom overflowed by 99870 pixels

```
class LocationListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Location> listOfLocations;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new LocationListView();
  LocationListWidget(this.listOfLocations);
}

class LocationListView extends State<LocationListWidget>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

TabController _controller;

  static const List<TopButtons> typeList = const <TopButtons>[
const TopButtons(title: "Places", icon: Icons.directions_walk),
const TopButtons(title: "Shop", icon: Icons.shop),
const TopButtons(title: "Vineyards", icon: Icons.local_drink),
const TopButtons(title: "Dining", icon: Icons.local_dining),
const TopButtons(title: "Cafes", icon: Icons.local_cafe),
const TopButtons(
  title: "Stay",
  icon: Icons.home,
)
    ];

  List<Location> listOfLocations;
  List<Location> fliteredlistOfLocations;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
listOfLocations = this.widget.listOfLocations;
fliteredlistOfLocations = new List();
_controller = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this,     initialIndex: 1);
_controller.addListener(updateList);
updateList();
  }

 void dispose() {
_controller.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Location"),
      bottom:
          TabBar(controller: _controller, isScrollable: true, tabs:      <Tab>[
        Tab(text: typeList[0].title, icon: Icon(typeList[0].icon)),
        Tab(text: typeList[1].title, icon: Icon(typeList[1].icon)),
        Tab(text: typeList[2].title, icon: Icon(typeList[2].icon)),
        Tab(text: typeList[3].title, icon: Icon(typeList[3].icon)),
        Tab(text: typeList[4].title, icon: Icon(typeList[4].icon)),
      ]),
    ),
    body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemExtent: 100.0,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            itemCount: fliteredlistOfLocations.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) =>
                buildBody(ctxt, index))));
  }
```

Comment: Could you check the rest of the error log? There's usually the specific line of where you error is happening. Also, for the bottom overflow, try wrapping your ListView with an Expanded widget, and the Expanded with a Column, removing then the SafeArea.

Comment: I am not 100% how to identify the error point in the log. Any direction would be helpful. The log goes all the way to line 141. See the last few lines.  
flutter: #140    ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #141    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)

Comment: The line for your error is usually shown on the first few lines, maybe between #1 and #5? Try to see if you find any that refers to your .dart file. Also, maybe fixing the listview layout sometimes works, as it could be pushing away the tab giving an error. So if could try debugging without the listview, only with a Text() element and see if it works. Then, try to check the first few erros lines :)

Comment: Just to clarify the "bottom overflowed by 99870 pixels" error is in the place where the tapbar should be. I feel like the the issues is that the tapbar isnt getting initialised properly and hence method are getting called on a null. If is step over the first error exception it then throws a failed assertion  "_currentTabOffsets != null" exception

Comment: already tried with just a text widget in place if the listview and it didnt help

Comment: Any of this help:flutter: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
flutter: #1      _TabStyle.build (package:flutter/src/material/tabs.dart:169:26)
flutter: #2      _AnimatedState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/transitions.dart:96:48)
flutter: #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3809:27)
flutter: #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:15)
flutter: #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)

Comment: flutter: #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
flutter: #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
flutter: #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
flutter: #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
flutter: #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a very similar issue. Here is how I fixed it:

I've added `unselectedLabelColor: Colors.red,` property in the `TabBar` widget. This stopped the error and tabs were working as expected.

In my case I've traced the issue back to `ThemeData`. I've implemented a custom theme for my app and this was the cause for this error. I've commented my custom theme and everything worked perfectly without any errors and without the need to add `unselectedLabelColor`.

Here is my final code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class AgendaScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _AgendaScreenState createState() => _AgendaScreenState();
    }

    class _AgendaScreenState extends State
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      TabController _tabController;

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              title: Text('Agenda', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: TabBar(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.red,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          'Audi 01',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        child: Text(
                          'Audi 02',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    controller: _tabController,
                    children: [
                      ListView(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.directions_transit)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
    }
```